# Samza/Flink/Spark: processing completion ("done" flag)

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-flink

Good day

My system consumes stream of trades and consists of multiple processing steps (jobs). Essentially it processes stream of trades and computes some metric over them (VaR). Source stream can be split in certain chunks (trades are grouped in portfolios). Currently I have home-grown solution and look to switch to Samza or Flink.

```
Trades                               Processors       Output

{<portfolio done>, t3, t2, t1} ->    A->B->...  ->   Measure
```

Fundamental question which I struggle with is - I need to understand when  portfolio is fully processed and figure in the output is complete. Basically I need to correlate the output (aggregated measure) with the input (which trades are processed resulting in this measure) so one can say "this figure reflects these trades". Ideally when all portfolios are processed, I need to record final figure.

Processing stages are non-trivial, they create intermediary streams (like return vectors), do some filtering, etc. so simple counting doesn't work.

I feel that my problem should be fairly standard, but can't find neither algorithm nor implementation in Samza or Flink.
Closest question I found is this one: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/samza-dev/201510.mbox/%3CCAA5FViH_2cz9CcS4VEo49HoWHF++QKyPB5t7y+bDCoVynZBqtg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Looks like similar to what I need can be implemented with `watermarks` functionality in Flink. Am I right?

Comment: Watermark only carry a timestamp. I doubt that you can exploit them -- this mechanism is rather internal as you could use it. Did you have a look into advanced windowing concepts of Flink? Triggers might be your friend.  https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/streaming_guide.html#windows-on-keyed-data-streams But is is hard to say exactly. If I understand you correctly, you "compute" the closing trade (ie, closing window) condition on the fly? How does this work?

Comment: Basically it works the way - source systems emits stream of trades, DAG processes them and accumulates some value. At some stage source system says "done, no more trades" and I need to wait until DAG fully catches up and save the value

Comment: Question on windows and triggers - will the system process the data from source during the period window is open? or will it try to buffer all incoming data, wait for window event and them process it as a batch?

Comment: If you get this special even from the source, you can define an custom trigger that waits for this event to close the window. Internally, the tuples are buffered and the window function is applied when the window is closed. (Incremental windows are on the agenda but not available yet.)

Comment: I think windows are not very appropriate here. Checkpoints seems more useful. Similar topic is discussed here: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-dev/201511.mbox/%3cCA+faj9xDFAUG_zi==E2H8s-8R4cn8ZBDON_hf+1Rud5pJqvZ4A@mail.gmail.com%3e
Basically they also think - once streaming job finishes, we need to propagate "done" flag though the DAG to finalise processing - exactly what I need.

So I am thinking, if I could trigger a checkpoint at Source manually, that would solve my task.
Can I somehow do that? Maybe by CheckpointCoordinator.triggerCheckpoint()? Is that a good idea at all?

Comment: Checkpointing is an internal mechanism. It enables Flink to backup system and UDF state such that it can recover in case of a failure. I am aware of the mail you mentioned, but I think it is a little of topic from your problem. I never played with checkpoints, but I guess you can customize them to some extend. But I don't think, this will help you. As fas as I know, all UDF are agnostic to checkpoints, ie, there is no way that you detect within your UDF when a checkpoint is done...

Comment: When using a a reduce over the window then the elements will be reduced as they arrive. This greatly reduces the number of elements that have to be kept in internal buffers. Basically Flink keeps only one element per key in that case.